# Why my original Binary search tree is getting modified even though I copied root node in another node?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My teacher gave us an assignment to code Binary Search Tree . Most of the part is done but I am having trouble with mirror image of binary tree.
Teacher told us that we should create a mirror image without altering the original tree. I tried to create it but code also modifies original BST as shown in my output below. I am not getting where it is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
        node *left,*right;
};
class BST
{
    node *root,*root1;
    public:
        int ch;
    BST(){   root=NULL;     ch=0;    }    
        void create();
    void insert(node*,node*);
    void disin();   
    void inorder(node*);
    void dispre();  
    void preorder(node*);
    void dispost(); 
    void postporder(node*);
    void search();
    node* actualsearch(node*,int);
    void min();
    void max();
    void actmin(node*);
    void actmax(node*);
    void height();
    int actheight(node*);
    void mirror();
    void actmirror(node*);
};
int main()
{
    int cho;
    BST b;
    char choice;
    do  {
    cout<<"\nEnter Your Choice = ";
    cout<<"\n1.Insert";
    cout<<"\n2.Inorder Traversal";
    cout<<"\n3.Preorder Traversal";
    cout<<"\n4.Postorder Traversal";
    cout<<"\n5.Search an element in tree";
    cout<<"\n6.Find Maximum element in tree";
    cout<<"\n7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree";
    cout<<"\n8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path";
    cout<<"\n9.Mirror Image = ";
    cin>>cho;
    switch(cho)
    {
        case 1:
            b.create();
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"---------------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\nInorder Treaversal = "<<endl;
            b.disin();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";      
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"---------------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\nPreorder Treaversal = "<<endl;
            b.dispre();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";      
            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"---------------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\nPostorder Treaversal = "<<endl;
            b.dispost();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";      
            break;  

        case 5:
            b.search();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";
            break;
        case 6:
            b.max();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";
            break;
        case 7:
            b.min();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";
            break;
        case 8:
            b.height();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";
            break;
        case 9:
            b.mirror();
            cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------";
            break;

    }
    cout<<"\nDo you want to continue opreations(y/n) = ";
    cin>>choice;    
    }while(choice=='y'||choice=='Y');
    return 0;
}

void BST::search()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"\nEnter element you want to search = ";
    cin>>n;
    if(root!=NULL)
        actualsearch(root,n);
    else
        cout<<"Tree is empty"<<endl;        
}
node* BST::actualsearch(node *current,int n)
{
    int dfcount=0;
    while(current)
    {
        if(current->data==n)
        {
            cout<<"Data Found"<<endl;
            dfcount++;
            break;
        }
        else if(n>current->data)
            {
                current=current->right;
            }
        else if(n<current->data)
            {
                current=current->left;
            }
    }
    if(dfcount==0)
    cout<<"Data not found!"<<endl;
    return NULL;
}

void BST::create()
{
    char ans;
    node *temp;
    do
    {
        temp=new node;
        temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
        cout<<"\nEnter no you want to insert = ";
        cin>>temp->data;
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(root,temp);
        }
        cout<<"\nDo You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = ";
        cin>>ans;
    }while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y');
}

void BST::insert(node *current,node *temp)
{
    if(temp->data==current->data)
        cout<<"\nDo not add";

    else if(temp->data<current->data)
    {
        if(current->left==NULL)
            current->left=temp;
        else
            insert(current->left,temp);
    }
    else if(temp->data>current->data)
    {
        if(current->right==NULL)
            current->right=temp;
        else
            insert(current->right,temp);
    }                   
}

void BST::disin()
{

    inorder(root);
}

void BST::inorder(node *T)
{   

    if(T!=NULL)
     {
        inorder(T->left);
        cout<<T->data<<" "; 
        inorder(T->right);
    }
}


void BST::dispre()
{

    preorder(root);
}

void BST::preorder(node *T)
{   

    if(T!=NULL)
     {
        cout<<T->data<<" "; 
        preorder(T->left);
        preorder(T->right);
    }
}


void BST::dispost()
{

    postporder(root);
}

void BST::postporder(node *T)
{   

    if(T!=NULL)
     {
        postporder(T->left);    
        postporder(T->right);
        cout<<T->data<<" "; 
    }
}
void BST::max()
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        actmax(root);
    }
}
void BST::min()
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        actmin(root);
    }
}
void BST::actmax(node* current)
{
    while(current->right!=NULL)
    {
        current=current->right;
    }
    cout<<"Largest Number is :"<<current->data<<endl;
}
void BST::actmin(node* current)
{
    while(current->left!=NULL)
    {
        current=current->left;
    }
    cout<<"Smallest Number is :"<<current->data<<endl;
}
void BST::height()
{
    int i=actheight(root);
    cout<<"Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path is:"<<i<<endl;
}
int BST::actheight(node* current)
{
    if(current==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int lh = actheight(current->left);
        int rh = actheight(current->right);
        if (lh > rh)  
           return(lh+1);
        else return(rh+1);
    }

}
void BST::mirror()
{   root1=root;
    actmirror(root1);
    cout<<"Mirror Image of given tree is Created!"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nInorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    inorder(root1);
    cout<<"\nPreorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    preorder(root1);
    cout<<"\nPostorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    postporder(root1);

}
void BST::actmirror(node* current)
{
    node* holder=new node;
    if(current==NULL)
    {
        return ;    
    }

    holder=current->left;
    current->left=current->right;
    current->right=holder;
    actmirror(current->left);
    actmirror(current->right);
}
```

Its output:

```
Enter Your Choice =
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 1

Enter no you want to insert = 5

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 6

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 7

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 2

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 3

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = n

Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice =
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 2
---------------------------------------------------
Inorder Treaversal =
2 3 5 6 7
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice =
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 9
Mirror Image of given tree is Created!

Inorder Travesral Is =
7 6 5 3 2
Preorder Travesral Is =
5 6 7 2 3
Postorder Travesral Is =
7 6 3 2 5
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice =
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 2
---------------------------------------------------
Inorder Treaversal =
7 6 5 3 2
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = n

--------------------------------
Process exited after 41 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here you can see that even though I used normal Inorder Traversal It doesn't show traversal of original BST rather it shows mirror BST's Traversal.

Comment: You need to create new nodes not modify existing ones.

Comment: I'd suspect [What is the rule of 3/5/0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is relevant here.

Comment: `void mirror();` -- Why is this not `BST mirror() const;`?  You are creating a new tree, no?  So return a new tree.  Also, all you need to do is "read" the existing tree to build the new tree, no?  If you did things this way, you would probably not have run into the issue you're seeing now (you would have coded things much differently, understanding that you cannot change the nodes in the existing tree, and the existing tree is read-only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Traversal It doesn't show traversal of original BST rather it shows mirror BST's Traversal.

in

> ```
> void BST::actmirror(node* current)
> {
>     node* holder=new node;
>     if(current==NULL)
>     {
>         return ;    
>     }
>
>     holder=current->left;
>     current->left=current->right;
>     current->right=holder;
>     actmirror(current->left);
>     actmirror(current->right);
> }
> ```

the allocated new *node* is lost because of `holder=current->left;` and you modify *current* rather than the new node as drescherjm said in a remark

---

A proposal : in the class *BST* change the signature of *BST::actmirror* to `node*  BST::actmirror(node* current)`, and its definition to :

```
node*  BST::actmirror(node* current)
{
    if(current==NULL)
    {
        return 0;    
    }

    node* holder=new node;

    holder->data = current->data;
    holder->left = actmirror(current->right);
    holder->right = actmirror(current->left);
    return holder;
}
```

as you see that do the mirror created at the same time a copy

and update *BST::mirror()* like that :

```
void BST::mirror()
{   node * copy1 = actmirror(root);
    cout<<"Mirror Image of given tree is Created!"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nInorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    inorder(copy1);
    cout<<"\nPreorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    preorder(copy1);
    cout<<"\nPostorder Travesral Is = "<<endl;
    postporder(copy1);

    // WARNING here you need to delete the copy !
}
```

As I said in a remark it is better if mirror make the copy and the mirror at the same time, I did that above.

And the execution is now :

```
Enter Your Choice = 
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 1

Enter no you want to insert = 5

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 6

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 7

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 2

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = y

Enter no you want to insert = 3

Do You want to continue to insert data(y/n) = n

Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice = 
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 2
---------------------------------------------------
Inorder Treaversal = 
2 3 5 6 7 
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice = 
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 9
Mirror Image of given tree is Created!

Inorder Travesral Is = 
7 6 5 3 2 
Preorder Travesral Is = 
5 6 7 2 3 
Postorder Travesral Is = 
7 6 3 2 5 
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = y

Enter Your Choice = 
1.Insert
2.Inorder Traversal
3.Preorder Traversal
4.Postorder Traversal
5.Search an element in tree
6.Find Maximum element in tree
7.Find Minimum elemnt in tree
8.Total No Of Nodes In Longest Path
9.Mirror Image = 2
---------------------------------------------------
Inorder Treaversal = 
2 3 5 6 7 
---------------------------------------------------
Do you want to continue opreations(y/n) = n
```

Comment: I am not able to get what you meant by `allocated node is lost`

Comment: @ShubhamWagh you do `node* holder=new node;` then `holder=current->left;` so the previous value of _holder_ being the new _node_ is lost

Comment: Oh I get it . But I still don't Understand how my original tree is getting modified.

Comment: You can't do this: `holder=current->left;` at all  or `current->left=current->right;` or `current->right=holder;` since current is a node in the original BST. You need to make  copies of your nodes.

Comment: Oh now I get it . Does that mean I have to Read all nodes and copy them again in another tree? Then perform mirror operation on that tree? as @PaulMcKenzie was saying?

Comment: @ShubhamWagh it is better to do the new tree indide pirror rather than copy then mirror

Comment: @ShubhamWagh I edited my answer to add a proposal of new definitions